# In SQL Server select record which are completed without going to resolved state

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find records in SQL Server which are marked as completed but they do not go through resolved state.

Here is the example below.

```
tracking_id task_id task status   old_status new_status_id
1195372     140717  ABC  Complete NULL       NULL
1195373     140717  ABC  Complete NULL       New
1195374     140717  ABC  Complete New        Completed
1195380     140718  XYZ  Complete NULL       NULL
1195381     140718  XYZ  Complete NULL       New
1195382     140718  XYZ  Complete New        Completed
1195383     140719  PQR  Complete NULL       NULL
1195384     140719  PQR  Complete NULL       Resolved
1195385     140719  PQR  Complete Resolved   Completed
```

Now in the table as **task_id 140717 and 140718** is marked as **Completed** but it never went to state **Resolved**. Where as **task_id 140719** is also marked completed but it goes through state Resolved. So I want to write **SQL Query** to just get record with **task_id 140717 and 140718.**

Any help with how to write query for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is better if you show us what is your desire result in same table format. Do Do you want `{140717, 140718}` or the rows with complete or all the rows with those ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
select * 
from yourtable t 
where status = 'Complete' 
and not exists 
     (select top 1 1 
      from yourtable o 
      where o.task_id = t.task_id 
      and o.old_status = 'Resolved')
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to make sure that a task ID has a "Completed" record, but not a "Resolved" record.

```
select ...
from the_table t_outer
where 
  status = 'Completed' and
  not exists (
    select 1 from the_table t_inner
    where 
      t_inner.task_id = t_outer.task_id and  -- same task
      'Resolved' in (t_inner.old_status, t_inner.new_status)
  )
```

(The whole status / new_status / old_status thing feels untidy.)

Comment: you dont neeed check for new status. Only for any old_status, the last status is `'Completed'`

Answer (score 1):

If the `old_status_id` is not always `'resolved'` for `'completed'` then using `not exists()`:

```
select *
from t
where new_status_id = 'completed'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from t as i
    where i.task_id = t.task_id
      and i.new_status_id = 'resolved'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only need the `task_id` not the row?

```
SELECT task_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN old_status = 'Resolved' THEN 1 END) = 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN new_status_id = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Now if you want all the record involve on those "incomplete" tasks

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT task_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY task_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN old_status = 'Resolved' THEN 1 END) = 0
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN new_status_id = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable Y
JOIN cte C
  ON Y.task_id = C.task_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable
where new_status_id = 'Completed'
      and old_status <> 'Resolved'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow some guides about select statements as this is very basic syntax.

Just use some where clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE old_status !+ 'Resolved'
AND new_status_id = 'Completed'
```